# Google Maps to OpenLayers - Marker Click Listener Equivalent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openlayers, openlayers-5, here-maps-rest

I am working with OpenLayers 5 trying to create the equivalent of a Google Maps Marker equivalent. I've been following the example here:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html

Unfortunately, it appears I can only add a listener to the map. Instead, I am trying to define the Icon(feature)'s Click event independent of the map. The function I am interested in calling from the click event is the `ngClick` function assigned to the Icon(feature)'s html element. With Google Maps I was able to implement the code below:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(scope.marker, 'click', function() {
     scope.$apply(function() {
         if (scope.ngClick) {
             scope.ngClick()
         }
     });
 });
```

Can anyone suggest what I am missing here? I believe earlier versions of OpenLayers had markers with events but I am unclear about how to get this to work in version 5.